# Table of all combinations possible with combination id

Tags: algorithm, abap, internal-tables

Here come a little ABAP challenge:

For an ABAP projet, i must build from an internal table with 2 columns (example1) another table containing all combinations possibles (example2).
"X" columns represent the parameter. "Y" represent the parameter value.

example1:

X(param)
    Y(value)

A   a1

A   a2

A   a3

B   b1

B   b2

C   c1

C   c2

In the result table (example2):
We must get all combinations with a numeric id (on 3 columns).
The new "z" column represent the combination id. For each combination there is a number of lines equal to the number of dictinct parameters(in our case 3 line for A,B and C).
"x" column still represent the parameter and "y" column the associated value.

example2:

z(combi num)
    x(param)
    y(value)

1   A   a1

1   B   b1

1   C   c1

2   A   a1

2   B   b1

2   C   c2

3   A   a1

3   B   b2

3   C   c1

4   A   a1

4   B   b2

4   C   c2

etc...
    etc...
    etc...

12  A   a3

12  B   b2

12  C   c2

Another remark is that the number of parameters and the number of values per parameters is not fixed (the initial internal table can evolve a lot and so the combinations possibles).

We maybe need recursion but i'm not sure of it.

Comment: Do you want the solution or guidance on how to solve it ? Are you familiar with Sorting  and usage of 'At New' blocks inside Loop ?

Comment: @TheG  : Solution will be appreciated. I already know what is SORT BY, LOOP and AT NEW. I know too that i must use it but i can't figure how -_-

Comment: Ok let me give it a shot . On further looking there emerges  a pattern but I see it is not as straightforward as it looked prima facie :)

Comment: @TheG : I already tried some ways... Like calculating first the total of combinations or building a table with the values count for each parameters. Everytimes i get an error or a headache ^^; There is maybe a way to do it without recursion, i'm still trying.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a homework assignment with no visible attempt by the poster to solve it...

Comment: I was close to the Gert Beukema solution except that in the main loop i was trying to loop again instead of dealing with index. Index make it so easy i can't imagine why i didn't tried it first !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a non-recursive way to do it, you might have to rewrite the parts that use the new 740 syntax. The idea is pretty simple, first transform the data into an internal table with one entry per parameter containing a table with the possible values, the LOOP loop. From there it is a simple matter of going through all the combinations and adding these to another internal table, the WHILE loop.

```
REPORT z_algorithm.

TYPES: ty_param TYPE char1,
       ty_value TYPE char2,
       BEGIN OF ty_struct,
         x TYPE ty_param,
         y TYPE ty_value,
       END OF ty_struct,
       BEGIN OF ty_combi,
         z TYPE i,
         s TYPE ty_struct,
       END OF ty_combi.
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_param_struct,
         x  TYPE ty_param,
         ys TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_value WITH DEFAULT KEY,
         ix TYPE i,
       END OF ty_param_struct.


DATA: tab      TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_struct,
      params   TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_param_struct,
      done     TYPE abap_bool VALUE abap_false,
      z        TYPE i VALUE 0,
      overflow TYPE abap_bool VALUE abap_false,
      combis   TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_combi.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  APPEND VALUE: #( x = 'A' y = 'a1' ) TO tab,
                #( x = 'A' y = 'a2' ) TO tab,
                #( x = 'A' y = 'a3' ) TO tab,
                #( x = 'B' y = 'b1' ) TO tab,
                #( x = 'B' y = 'b2' ) TO tab,
                #( x = 'C' y = 'c1' ) TO tab,
                #( x = 'C' y = 'c2' ) TO tab.

  LOOP AT tab ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<tab>).
    READ TABLE params WITH KEY x = <tab>-x ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<param>).
    IF sy-subrc NE 0.
      APPEND INITIAL LINE TO params ASSIGNING <param>.
      <param>-x = <tab>-x.
      <param>-ix = 1.
    ENDIF.
    APPEND <tab>-y TO <param>-ys.
  ENDLOOP.

  WHILE done EQ abap_false.

    ADD 1 TO z.
    overflow = abap_true.
    done = abap_true.

    LOOP AT params ASSIGNING <param>.

      READ TABLE <param>-ys INDEX <param>-ix ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<y>).
      APPEND VALUE #( z = z s-x = <param>-x s-y = <y> ) TO combis.

      IF overflow EQ abap_true.
        ADD 1 TO <param>-ix.
      ENDIF.

      IF <param>-ix GT lines( <param>-ys ).
        overflow = abap_true.
        <param>-ix = 1.
      ELSE.
        overflow = abap_false.
        done = abap_false.
      ENDIF.

    ENDLOOP.

  ENDWHILE.
```

Comment: I'm impressed ! I translated it in old abap version and it works like a charm. You cheated a little by changing the output table adding a structure into it but it's so short compared to my previous atempts. Really nice ! (I edited your post to add the old abap version).